# Android build tool command aapt "cannot execute binary file"

Tags: android, linux, redhat, android-build

I have build tools version 25.0.1 installed on a machine running Enterprise Red Hat Linux, 64 bit.  When I try and run the aapt command, from the command line I get the following:

```
-bash: ./aapt: cannot execute binary file
```

From researching it looks like the issue is that the aapt executable was compiled for 32 bit.  I have tried many suggestions out there to install via yum libs to allow 32 bit executables to run, but none have let aapt run.

Here is the output from `file ./aapt`

```
./aapt: Mach-O 64-bit executable
```

Here is the output from the uname command

```
3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 19 11:24:13 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This question was asked and answered [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334655/android-build-tool-command-aapt-cannot-execute-binary-file/334656).